# Prove that $n^2<4^n$ by induction

Tags: induction

I need to prove by induction that $n^2<4^n$ can you please help me with that?
I tried a few things already but with no success.

What I did: From $n^2<4^n$ I got to $4n^2<4^{n+1}$. After that I got to $(2n)^2<4^{n+1}$, so I thought that $(n+1)^2<(2n)^2<4^{n+1}$ but it doesn't seem to match the definition of $n$ which is $n\geq0$.

Comment: $4=2^2$ so $4^n=2^{2n}=(2^n)^2$. The problem is reduced to an even easier one: $n<2^n$ which is true for $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Show, in this case, the proposition holds for $n = 1$ (aka, establish the basis step as true).  Then, assume $n^2 \lt 4^n$ (the Induction hypothesis we'll be referring back to).  Finally, given the assumption that $n^2 \lt 4^n$, prove that it must then hold for $(n+1)$: Prove that the induction hypothesis implies $$(n+1)^2 \lt 4^{n+1} \iff n^2 + 2n + 1 \lt 4\cdot 4^n$$ $(n^2 + (2n+1))\lt (4^n + 3\cdot 4^n)$, and since $n^2 \lt 4^n,$ by the inductive hypothesis,  so we need only show that $2n+1\leq 3\cdot 4^n $.  Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

For $n>1$ we have $n^2> n$ and $n^2> 1$ so $4n^2=n^2+2n^2+n^2> n^2+2n+1$. I would either take two base cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ or I would prove the case when $n=0$ by simply plugging in $n=0$.